# System.InvalidOperationException: Error on updating the table through datagridview using dt.update method

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataadapter

I have a problem with updating the table through data grid view with a button click.
here's my code.

```
Public Sub loaddgvfrm3()
    cmdconn = New SqlConnection
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmdconn.ConnectionString = sqlstr
    cmdconn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn
    cmd.CommandText = "select  period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated, year_student from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + txtClaimno.Text + "'"
    'cmd.CommandText = "select  a.period, a.VOUCH_AMT, a.INDIVIDUAL_AMT, a.check_no, a.bal_ent, a.D_MAILED, a.DIR_NO from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY a left join carlos.claims_waivee b on a.CLAIM_NO = b.claim_no where b.CLAIM_NO like '" + claimno.ToString + "'"

    'Dim ds As New DataTable
    'Dim cmdbuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    'da = New SqlDataAdapter()
    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
    cmdconn.Close()

End Sub
```

the code above is the datagridview content where i put my select statement. and that datagridview is i am modifying right now

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click



    Try

        cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(dt)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
        'End If
        MsgBox("changes done")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

whenever i click the save button after modifying a certain row, an error log comes out,

the error look's like this:

System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.
 at system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatingrowstatusErrors(RowUpdatingeventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, DataRow datarow)
at System.data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tablemapping)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
at Educational.frmEb.btnSave_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e) in
C:\Users\Fox\Documents\Stress Test\Educational\form3.vb:line 220

but program still continues.
i can't see any changes i made in the DGV to database.
is there something that i'm missing?

here's my declaration

```
Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"
Dim cmdconn = New SqlConnection
Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim dt As New DataTable
```

prior to that error, they say that i need to set a primary key/unique key in the database, so i did, but the same error comes out.

pls help me, im really stuck at this phase, i'll be forever in gratitude if you do so, as it is the last part of my project. updating changes i made from dgv to database using da.update stuffs.

Comment: It would help to show the database table in question, but my feeling is that it doesn't have a primary key

Comment: i did create a primary key on the selected table, but the same error comes out.

Comment: I don't see your SelectCommand on the SqlDataAdapter, please show this

Comment: there' i've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

The command builder can only generate an UpdateCommand and a DeleteCommand if:

1. The SelectCommand queries a single table.
2. That table has a primary key.
3. That primary key is known to the data adapter.

If you already have 1 and 2 convered, make sure that the MissingSchemaAction property of the data adapter is set to AddWithKey.

Comment: where can i find the missingSchemaAction property?

Comment: On your SqlDataAdapter. If you say that your table does have a primary key, then this is probably the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Was it my imagination?  Did I just think that I typed "the MissingSchemaAction property **of the data adapter**" and I didn't really?  Even if I hadn't, is the Help menu on your IDE broken?

Comment: yes, u probably typed it, honestly, it is my first time to use this Visual studio. now you have the idea how unfamiliar i am with this platform. :(

Comment: i did what 3 is, but another error comes out : System.argumentOutOfrangeException: the missingmappingaction enumeration value, 4, is invalid. parameter name :MissingMappingACtion

Comment: Where I come from, MissingSchemaAction, which is what I told you to set, and MissingMappingAction, which you apparently did set, are not the same thing.  I understand being new to something; I really do.  I even understand not reading something correctly the first time.  Not re-reading it and discovering your mistake when it doesn't work the first time... that is something that I don't understand.  I come here to help people by answering their questions, so I have no problem writing an answer.  Writing that answer twice more because they don't read properly is pushing things a bit.

Comment: yeah. cuz when i write the missingschemaaction = addwithkey, it actually returned the same error, so i tried new solution to get rid of the current error, (then i saw this syntax that the missingschemaaction is incorporated with missingmappingaction so i did try that out, then the error showed above) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.missingschemaaction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and btw, i did put this code "da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey" in both subs,(alternately) (btnsave sub and loaddgvfm3) just to see how things are gonna work out (cuz i don't know where to put it though) but still the same error returns.

Comment: You would set the MissingSchemaAction property before calling Fill on the data adapter, because that's when the missing schema is added to the DataTable.

Comment: yeah. i did that, but the same error occur. the  System.InvalidOperationException still pops out. any idea why it is still returning the error aside from 1 2 3?